# Log4Net fails to log on application closing event

Tags: c#, wpf, log4net

I'm currently developing an WPF application in C#.
I now want to log the closing of the application.
Log4Net works as it should in all parts of my program. (Except for this)

Example:

`The user clicks the default red "X" button every Windows Program has, the log should show "Application Closed"`

I created an behavior for the `Closing` event (this is where I want to log), BUT here Log4Net just Fails to Log.

I tried:

```
Log.Flush();
Log.Dispose();
```

both failed to do the job.
The only thing that seems to work is the delaying of the actual closing by Opening a `MessageBox`, or doing a `Thread.Sleep(1000)`

Is there a better Solution for this?

Comment: I suspect some funny WPF behavior specific to your application, I have not yet seen Log4Net have such timing troubles. Just to verify, did you instead try to handle the `Closing` event in code-behind? Does that make any difference?

Comment: This didn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

You can call shutdown on you [LogManager.Shutdown](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.LogManager.Shutdown.html):

```
LogManager.Shutdown();
```

> Calling this method will safely close and remove all appenders in all the loggers including root contained in all the default repositories. 
>   Some appenders need to be closed before the application exists. Otherwise, pending logging events might be lost. 
>   The shutdown method is careful to close nested appenders before closing regular appenders. This is allows configurations where a regular appender is attached to a logger and again to a nested appender.

Comment: Thank you for your effeort, I figured out that it was my own fault

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my problem was, this *wasn't* the fault of log4net istself.

The problem was that I was using an company specific wrapper sitting on top of log4net. This was causing the logging to be not correctly flushed to the file.

I was calling `Log.Flush()` and then `Log.Dispose()` directly afterwards so the dispose canceled the Flush.

Now I'm only calling `Log.Flush()` and it works flawless.